# Here GPS tracking

Tags: security, privacy, dns, firewall

I have been lured into the world of FOSS apps, apps using known trackers and loggers, DNS, and firewalls. My phone is rooted via Magisk. It's a Huawei P20 Lite. Running Havoc 2.9 and Android 9.

So I have started replacing all the Google store apps with new open-source apps found on FOSS and F-droid.

Currently, I am running RethinkDNS providing Firewall and DNS services. So looking through the resolved queries and the firewall log of RethinkDNS, I found an internal IP (used PCAPdroid for packet capture) on UDP port 53 which resolves to `sodium.slp.pos.here.com`.)

I have read up on Here's services which is location-based tracking for apps using HERE's SDK. My phone does not have a Google Play Store installed. I used MicroG for a while until I started moving over to other open-source apps.

Looking at the packet data, PCAPdroid does a good job of finding the apps which connect to Google's or other servers for tracking purposes. So then I go ahead and look for an alternative app on the above-mentioned app stores.

Also, I used ClassyShark3xodus and found so juicy titbits on trackers/loggers on my phone. Loggers from what I read up are not all that bad for app devs (GitHub?).

Currently, I have RethinkDNS blocking UDP traffic from unknown apps.

The following is captured via PCAPdroid.

```
IPProto SrcIP   SrcPort DstIp   DstPort Uid App Proto   Status  Info    BytesSent   BytesRcvd   PktsSent    PktsRcvd    
17  10.215.173.1    39132   10.215.173.2    53  1051    netd    DNS Closed  sodium.slp.pos.here.com 69  527 1   1   
6   10.215.173.1    59738   3.124.142.17    443 1021    GPS TCP Closed      657 120 3   3   1617287557  
17  10.215.173.1    52141   10.215.173.2    53  1051    netd    UDP Closed      138 0   2   0   1617287634
```

Also from what I have read, and please correct me when I am wrong! This is how `netd` sends network-related info to other Android services requesting such network traffic.

Currently, I am blocking via RethinkDNS all GPS-related requests. Now I am not interested in any GPS service. I just want to know where my traffic is heading.

Also, I tried Bitwarden to find the origin of these requests to no avail.
Any help or info would be greatly appreciated as I want to learn how all these things connect.

Comment: I would expect a network connection by the GPS deamon to load the AGPS data. Instead of denying everything I would allow it and intercept + capture the data. Then you will see what data is actually sent.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thank you for the reply! Well I did exactly that as you mentioned. I only have a bit of networking experience. Nothing to write home about :-)

I inspected the packets captured. Yet WireShark is a complicated app. I have gone through the UDP & TCP packets. There was more info I got from those packets as suggested by you. What I did relaize is that it originates from an internal private server with a 10.#.#.# address. That is the address initiating the requests. Here is the other info I gathered from the packets. (dualstack.pra-slpposhere-2023804607.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.)